# Changing node/job fee from 1 LINK

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I've set up my own node and job according to the documentation - https://docs.chain.link/docs/fulfilling-requests/

Everything works correctly as long as the ORACLE_PAYMENT is set to 1 LINK. I'm expecting a lot of requests and I wouldn't want to buy thousands of LINK, so I would like to lower this fee. I've tried changing it to 0.01 and there was no error but the job doesn't get called unless it's 1.

How can I adjust this fee?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the fee by using the [MINIMUM_CONTRACT_PAYMENT_LINK_JUELS](https://docs.chain.link/docs/configuration-variables/#minimum_contract_payment_link_juels).

Add next line to your job to set fee to 0.01 LINK

```
minContractPaymentLinkJuels = 10000000000000000
```

Or add the next line to your `.env` file to set up it on node globally

```
MINIMUM_CONTRACT_PAYMENT_LINK_JUELS = 10000000000000000
```

Finally, double-check that `ORACLE_PAYMENT` variable in smart contract matches this value.